# How can I export all functions of a JavaScript object as module without having to make a lot of changes to the file?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have [this raw non-modular JavaScript file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ststeiger/FirstPWA/master/FirstPWA/wwwroot/scripts/luxon-1.11.4.js) (luxon.js).

Then I have a JavaScript file (actually TypeScript) where I import it like this:

```
import * as luxon from './luxon.js';
```

So no I need to turn luxon.js into a module.
I do this by removing

```
var luxon = (function (exports) {
```

and

```
}({}));
```

Then, I add the following line at the end.

```
export { DateTime, Duration, Interval, Info, Zone, FixedOffsetZone, IANAZone, InvalidZone, LocalZone, Settings };
```

And [that](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ststeiger/FirstPWA/master/FirstPWA/wwwroot/ts/PWA2/luxon.js) works fine (in google-chrome).
But suppose this were a lot more functions.
How can I do something like

```
exports exports;
```

or

```
 export * from exports;
```

so I don't have to manually enumerate all functions that are already in the object "exports" ?

Note: 
The object exports exists, and has all functions to be exported already assigned to itselfs.

```
var exports = {};

exports.DateTime = DateTime;
exports.Duration = Duration;
exports.Interval = Interval;
exports.Info = Info;
exports.Zone = Zone;
exports.FixedOffsetZone = FixedOffsetZone;
exports.IANAZone = IANAZone;
exports.InvalidZone = InvalidZone;
exports.LocalZone = LocalZone;
exports.Settings = Settings;
```

Also note please don't provide me links to a npm repository where luxon has already been modularized. 
I'm not interested in luxon specifically, I'm interested in how to quickly modularize something that's not a module just yet (with minimal effort).

Comment: @Rajesh: export (function (exports) { ... }({})); doesn't work. SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'. I tried that already.

Comment: Uh, why do you have luxon as a raw non-modular script? Just [use their module](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html#es6)! This is not luxon-specific - don't start with a transpiler output, always start with the actual source, which [often already is an ES6 module](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/luxon.js)

Comment: @Bergi: Didn't I write I'm interested in modularizing scripts ? I'm not interested in luxon itselfs.

Comment: "*So that I don't have to manually enumerate all functions*" - no, that's not possible. In an ES6 module, you always need to explicitly declare all exports.

Comment: @Bergi: Oh that sucks. Also, their module is not ES6 compatible.

Comment: What do you mean by "*their module is not ES6 compatible*"?

Comment: @Bergi: The one listed as "AMD (System.js, RequireJS, etc)". Ah I see, below is ES6. OK that would work.  Never mind. Great, so ES6 is incompatible with UMD...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somewhat managed to do it. I'll recommend using [ES6 version](https://moment.github.io/luxon/es6/luxon.js) of library for your purpose. If you still want to use [browser global version](https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.js) as modules follow these steps.

***changes in luxon.js :***

change this

```
var luxon = (function (exports) {
  'use strict';
```

by this

```
export default (function (exports) {
'use strict'
```

***index.html***

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

***index.js***

```
import luxon from "./luxon.js";
console.log(luxon.DateTime.local().setZone('America/New_York').minus({ weeks: 1 }).endOf('day').toISO());
```

Comment: Fascinating, it works in JavaScript, but TypeScript has problems with this in the definition file.

Comment: @Stefan , I have no idea what is issue with TS. Kindly check [github issue 3337](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3337) I hope you'll find the solution.